# How can I check if a number is a multiple of 50 in C#

Tags: c#

I have a loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scrapedWikiWords.Capacity; i++) 
{
   // code
   Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

How can I make it so the Console will only print numbers for when  i = 0, 50, 100, 150 etc.

Comment: Modulo operator?

Comment: That sequence is a ***multiple*** of 50.  Powers of 50 would be, `0, 50, 2500, 125000...`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using `Capacity` rather than `Count`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the modulus operator (`%`) operator:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++)
{
    if (i % 50 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: Why did you change `<` to `<=`?  Why did you change `scrapedWikiWords.capacity` to the hardcoded value 200??

Comment: @abelenky: To answer the OP's question about "*only print numbers for when i = 0, 50, 100, 150 etc*". Obviously 200 is just an example. `scrapedWikiWords.Capacity` has nothing to do with the solution or question. Why did you downvote the answer? :)

Answer (score 4):

You could simply increase `i` by 50 instead of by 1, for example like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < scrapedWikiWords.Capacity; i += 50) { }
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. Given that the OP wants _multiples_ instead of _powers_ (which they did not yet clarify,though), this solution is superior to the modulo operator.

Comment: @RenéVogt, While I don't mind a question for "Generating multiple of n?". This question will be hard to lookup on any Search engine. I don't even get why we have answers here. I found it harder to click "this answer is usefull" for any of those. Im just lost by the general voting pattern on those low question.

Comment: Look at the variable name:  `scrapedWikiWord`; they are not looking to process every 50th word.... they are looking to process *every* word, and only a `Console.Write` to update the user after 50 words have been processed. Similar to a progress bar that shows how much work has been done.  Hence the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < scrapedWikiWords.Capacity; i++) 
{
   processWikiWord(....);

   if (i % 50 == 0)
   {   // Update the user after 50, 100, 150, 200... words.
       // (Updating after every single word would be way too much output!)
       Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
}
```

The Modulo operator returns the remainder of division.

For example:

```
20 / 3 == 6 with a remainder of 2; 
20 % 3 == 2 (the remainder part)
```

The consequence is that any number Modulo N always results in a value between `0` and `N-1`.

Doing Modulo 50 means you will always get a result between 0 and 49.
The result will be 0 when the values of `i` are 50, 100, 150, 200, 250,...
The rest of the time the value will be somewhere between 1 and 49, and the if-statement will be skipped.